# Question regarding the definition of different of a number field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field. I was getting a bit confused, because different sources I looked into had different definitions. I was wondering if they were equivalent or not. And if they are how can I prove it?

In one source it defines it to be the inverse of 
$$
I_1 = \{ x \in K : Tr(xy) \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ for all } y \in O_K \},
$$
where $O_K$ is the ring of integers of $K$. 
On other place, it said the different is the inverse of 
$$
I_2 = \{ x \in K : Tr(x) \in \mathbb{Z} \}.
$$
Are these the same thing? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one is not correct, for sure: many non-integers have trace $0$.

Edit: in more detail, the inverse different of the ring of integers $\mathfrak o$ of a number field $k$ is $\{\beta\in k:\mathrm{tr}^k_{\mathbb Q} (\alpha\beta)\in\mathbb Z\;\hbox{for all $\alpha\in \mathfrak o$}\}$. This is much smaller than the collection of things with integer trace, because this latter condition is just $\mathrm{tr}^k_{\mathbb Q}(\beta\cdot 1)$. For example, in $k=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})$, $\beta=\sqrt{d}/1000$ has trace $0$, hence trace in $\mathbb Z$, but is probably not an algebraic integer.

Comment: Thank you for the details. Some how I am still not seeing it... $\beta = \sqrt{d}/1000$ has trace $0$, and it's probably not an algebraic integer I get. I know that the different is integral, but the inverse of different is not necessarily an integral ideal, so I am not quite sure how this helps at the moment... What am I missing here?

Comment: The trace of $c\cdot \sqrt{d}$ is $c\cdot \sqrt{d}+c\cdot (-\sqrt{d})=0$.

Comment: I know that the trace of your $\beta$ is $0$, and that it is not an algebraic integer. But I don't quite see how this helps...

Comment: Thus, if the second definition were correct, every $1/c\cdot \sqrt{d}$ would be an algebraic integer, and this is not correct. So the second definition is not correct. Also, similarly, the second definition does not define a fractional ideal... It's just messed-up.